# Genserver Phoenix Issue

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gen-server

I am getting data from an endpoint as a list, assume they are unique id's I  attempt to start a GenServer process for each of them but the processes are terminated as soon they are started but the error is unclear, I cant seem to find what is killing the process, here is my sample code below and error trying to debug. NB ("I can however start a process with a single transaction", also when I call Enum. each() with the id's and attempt to start the GenServer in the command line it works successfully ). what exactly is happening when the list comes from an endpoint because the can be printed clearly and the processes started successfully but they are terminated immediately also?.

```
def new(conn, %{"hashes" => [_ | _] = hashes}) do
    # Enum.each the list of hashes call hash fn on each hash
    # needs more debugging the function is glitching "some processes failing"
    hashes
    |>Enum.each(fn hash ->  call_hash(conn,hash) end)  #research more queing calls?
  end


  defp call_hash(conn,hash) do
    with {:ok, _} <- GenServer.start_link(TransactionSubscriptionHandler, %{hash: 
  String.to_atom(hash)}, name: String.to_atom(hash))
        #  {:ok, %{status: 200}} <- BlockNative.subscribe_transaction(hash)
         do
         json(conn,%{status: "Ok"})
        else
     _ -> conn |> put_status(400) |> json(%{status: "Failed"})
  end

  end
```

input

```
"hashes": [
        "0x04b08ab13d51613975cd5035cebb52d5f574137c42902a5b1147f953f1895c6a",
        "0x2285dfeafe2eae5846fe66bd9631f2d258c1d5b32702649153c9073a3a4ec8ad"
    ]
```

output from the command line

```
[info] POST /api/transaction
[debug] Processing with VhsWeb.TransactionController.new/2
  Parameters: %{"hashes" => ["0x04b08ab13d51613975cd5035cebb52d5f574137c42902a5b1147f953f1895c6a", "0x2285dfeafe2eae5846fe66bd9631f2d258c1d5b32702649153c9073a3a4ec8ad"]}
  Pipelines: [:api]
{:ok, #PID<0.597.0>}
[info] Sent 200 in 2ms
{:ok, #PID<0.598.0>}
[info] Sent 200 in 2ms
[error] Ranch listener VhsWeb.Endpoint.HTTP had connection process started with :cowboy_clear:start_link/4 at #PID<0.594.0> exit with reason: {:function_clause, [{:cowboy_http, :commands, [{:state, #PID<0.471.0>, VhsWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, #Port<0.22>, :ranch_tcp, :undefined, %{env: %{dispatch: [{:_, [], [{:_, [], Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler, {VhsWeb.Endpoint, []}}]}]}, stream_handlers: [:cowboy_telemetry_h, :cowboy_stream_h]}, "", %{}, {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 34624}, {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 4000}, :undefined, #Reference<0.3145460136.2965635073.81437>, 2, {:ps_request_line, 0}, :infinity, 1, :done, 100, [{:stream, 1, {:cowboy_telemetry_h, {:state, {:cowboy_stream_h, {:state, :undefined, VhsWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, #PID<0.595.0>, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, :undefined, 0, :fin, "", 180, :undefined, ...}}, #Function<0.122385210/1 in :cowboy_telemetry_h."-fun.metrics_callback/1-">, :undefined, %{body_length: 180, cert: :undefined, has_body: true, headers: %{"accept" => "*/*", "accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br", "connection" => "keep-alive", "content-length" => "180", "content-type" => "application/json", "host" => "localhost:4000", "postman-token" => "ad48096e-c775-4f82-a860-a4d4b4286c9c", "user-agent" => "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8"}, host: "localhost", method: "POST", path: "/api/transaction", peer: {{127, 0, 0, ...}, 34624}, pid: #PID<0.594.0>, port: 4000, qs: "", ref: VhsWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, ...}, "200 OK", %{"cache-control" => "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-length" => "15", "content-type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date" => "Mon, 03 May 2021 20:41:43 GMT", "server" => "Cowboy", "x-request-id" => "FnupLbYol1vbVZsAAABE"}, VhsWeb.Endpoint.HTTP, -576460686234141769, :undefined, -576460686234115433, -576460686234115433, -576460686203746015, -576460686203746015, %{#PID<0.595.0> => %{spawn: -576460686234129902}}, [], 180, ...}}, "POST", :"HTTP/1.1", :undefined, :undefined, 0, []}], [{:child, #PID<0.595.0>, 1, 5000, :undefined}]}, 1, [{:response, "200 OK", %{"cache-control" => "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-length" => "15", "content-type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date" => "Mon, 03 May 2021 20:41:43 GMT", "server" => "Cowboy", "x-request-id" => "FnupLbYol1vbVZsAAABE"}, ["{\"", [[] | "status"], "\":", [34, [[] | "Ok"], 34], 125]}]], [file: '/home/edwin/dev/phoenix-projects/vhs/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_http.erl', line: 922]}, {:cowboy_http, :loop, 1, [file: '/home/edwin/dev/phoenix-projects/vhs/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_http.erl', line: 231]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}
```

Comment: That cowboy error is hard to read, but it looks like it is encountering undefined stuff.  It looks like it's trying to have a separate web-server process handle each item in your list, and that might be making things fail because I think the main Phoenix process receives incoming messages.  Your intention isn't to spin up multiple web-servers, right?

Comment: yes I want to start multiple GenServer processes

Answer (score 1):

Many processes have nothing to do with the issue. Here is the simplified code that would raise the same error.

```elixir
def new(conn, _),
  do: ["1", "2"] |> Enum.each(&call_hash(conn, &1))

defp call_hash(conn, _) do
  json(conn, %{status: "Ok"})
end
```

That said, you are trying to send many responses to the single `POST` request, which obviously fails, because `conn` gets terminated after the first one response is sent.

Comment: how can I structure call_hash to return the updated conn after the first call and in the event of an error, return a response but not to kill my processes

Comment: Use [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce_while/3) on `hashes`, terminate if the process has not been started and _only after_ call `json/2` or return the response in any other way. Basically, `json/2` should be called from `new/2` *after* all calls to `hash_call/2`.